# Android - Calculating Battery Charging or Discharging rate

Tags: android, android-intent, batterylevel

I am trying to calculate battery charging or discharging rate. I use ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED to receive the event and I wait for minimum 1% change. Then I divide difference in battery level by difference in time (milliseconds). I multiply the result by 1000 * 60 * 60 to show the rate in "% per hour unit". But I am not sure if I am doing it right or there's some mistake. Because, sometimes it shows charging or discharging at around 6% or 15% which seems right. But sometimes it shows around 15000%.

So can anyone please tell me what's wrong with this code.

Here's my code:

Registering:

```
IntentFilter batteryLevelFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
registerReceiver(new EnReceiverOnBatteryChange(), batteryLevelFilter)
```

Receiver:

```
public class EnReceiverOnBatteryChange extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Utils.recordChargeOrDischargeRate(context);
        ActivityHome.updateBatteryInfo(context);
    }
}
```

Calculation:

```
public static void recordChargeOrDischargeRate(Context context)
{
    long lCurrentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    float fCurrentBatteryLevel = 0;

    float fRate = 0;
    if ((mfLastBatteryLevel != -1) && (mlLastTime != -1))
    {
        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Konstant.PREFERENCES_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = preferences.edit();

        IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);

        int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
        int scale = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

        if (level != -1 && scale != -1)
        {
            fCurrentBatteryLevel = 100 * level / (float) scale;
        }

        float fBatteryLevelDifference = Math.abs(fCurrentBatteryLevel - mfLastBatteryLevel);
        if (fBatteryLevelDifference > 0.99)
        {
            fRate = (fBatteryLevelDifference / (lCurrentTime - mlLastTime)) * 1000 * 60;

            prefEditor.putString(Konstant.KEY_PREF_CHARGING_START_RATE, String.format("%.2f", (fRate * 60)) + "%");
            prefEditor.commit();

            int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
            boolean isCharging = (status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING || status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL);

            if (isCharging)
            {
                int nMinutes = Math.round((100 - fCurrentBatteryLevel) / fRate);
                int nHour = nMinutes / 60;
                nMinutes = nMinutes % 60;
                prefEditor.putString(Konstant.KEY_PREF_FULL_CHARGE_IN, nHour + "h " + nMinutes + "m");
                prefEditor.commit();
            }
            else
            {
                int nMinutes = Math.round(fCurrentBatteryLevel / fRate);
                int nHour = nMinutes / 60;
                nMinutes = nMinutes % 60;
                prefEditor.putString(Konstant.KEY_PREF_FULL_CHARGE_IN, nHour + "h " + nMinutes + "m");
                prefEditor.commit();
            }

            mlLastTime = lCurrentTime;
            mfLastBatteryLevel = fCurrentBatteryLevel;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        mlLastTime = lCurrentTime;
        mfLastBatteryLevel = fCurrentBatteryLevel;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sometimes it shows charging or discharging at 15000%" ? Otherwise your method is kinda correct: you calculate the amount of time it took to lost X charge, and try to estimate how much time is left based on previous rates. It's never accurate in fact.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zss2dpns74irrq5/Screenshot_2014-04-10-06-58-26.png If you look at this image, it shows 155% and it is obvious that 44% battery level wont be drained in 17m. So, the battery is not discharging at 155% per hour rate. So, my doubt is why do i get so fluctuated numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the battery state diagram in the android options. The energy usage rate of your phone sometimes changes quite drastically on smaller timescales - though it looks constant on the larger timescale. 
I can be wrong, but maybe you should better look for a few minutes time difference, rather than the 1% battery level difference.